# Activation Context Generation Failed error in manifest or policy .invalid xml syntax

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xml-parsing, zip, app-config

I Have a windows application that uses another application to update its version files.
In my App , I saved the changed xml and Exe files in my database and every time the app runs , It downloads the xml and other files from database and pastes them in the app path (folder).

The downloading and pasting sections are working correctly .But when I want to execute the new replaced .exe file by shell method, It crashes.

Also when I want to run the new exe file  manually, I see the following error: "The Application has failed to start because it's side-by-side configuration is incorrect" .

After checking the event Log, I saw the following error: "Activation Context Generation Failed for D:\FolderName\appname.exe error in manifest or policy file"

UPDATE: When Updater download exe.config file, Its xmldocument gets changed and shows the following error : character ' ' hexadecimal value 0x0 is illegal in xml documents.

Comment: Have you tried using sxstrace ? https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=sxstrace

Comment: BTW what do you mean by "pasting" the file?

Comment: Hi @StayOnTarget , I mean Coying And Pasting the files

Comment: Yes , I saw that and tried All the solutions

Comment: What was the output of sxstrace? You should edit the question to add this

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by copy & paste. Is the program downloading a file and then saving it locally? I thought that's what it meant.

Comment: @StayOnTarget  Yes

Comment: regarding the config file, I would diff the downloaded copy with the original and see what's changed